# Refresh Textview instantly

Tags: android, textview

This is my code

```
try {
final double calcResult = CalcUtils.evaluate(textViewOutputScreen.getText().toString());

textViewOutputScreen.setText(Double.toString(calcResult)); //setting text to text view   

new voices().voice(calcResult);  //this method takes about 5-10 seconds to execute

} catch (Exception e) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textViewOutputScreen.setText("0");
 }
```

the text  which I set to the `TextView`  in second line is updating on the screen after 5-10 seconds ,i.e after the method  new voices().voice(calcResult); is finished execution.

I kept few delays like this in method

```
            try {
                Thread.sleep(700);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want to refresh the text view before the method is called how can I do it?

I searched for similar questions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try invalidating the view before running the `new voices().voice(calcResult);`

```
textViewOutputScreen.invalidate();
```

If that doen't work you could try putting the heavy load on a `AsyncTask`

It executes in the background and is based on Java Thread. You could add `AsyncTask` as a nested class in you current `class`/`Activity`

```
private class VoiceTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground(Double... stuff) {
         //Do whatever voice does!
         double calcResult = stuff[0];
         new voices().voice(calcResult);


     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //Is called when you are done, if you want to send stuff here
         //you need to change this example, see the link below
         //Not necessary to override (If I remember correctly)
     }
 }
```

[[Link to AsyncTask examples]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Next you just create an AsyncTask and execute it with you parameter. the value will be available in `doInBackground`.

```
try {
      final double calcResult = CalcUtils.evaluate(textViewOutputScreen.getText().toString());

                textViewOutputScreen.setText(Double.toString(calcResult)); //setting text to text view 
                new VoiceTask().execute(calcResult);  //CHANGED LINE

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textViewOutputScreen.setText("0");
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , tried to invalidate but still not working

Comment: Then you should try what robert says. Try putting the `new voices().voice(calcResult);` in a background thread. Pro tip is checking `AsyncTask` out. and doing the heavy stuff in the background

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are executing your code in the `main`thread, and the `TextView.setText(...)` get placed last in the `event queue` and therefore it get's updated after the `new Voices().voice()` has finished execution.

You could try to update the `TextView` from the `UI Thread` by following:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textViewOutputScreen.setText(Double.toString(calcResult));
    }
});
```

A much nicer solution would of course be to run the long running task in the background...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply , tried this but its still not working